# Is there any way i can buid an android app/content blocker in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create an android app that can block content/apps whenever something happens but i cant find any documentation in Flutter. I understand that what i want to do is more of native. Any recommendations.

Comment: Do you have an example of such an app? "block content/apps" is fairly ambiguous. It could mean block notifications or something completely different

Comment: okay i wish to block social media when i enter some location or when something is happening. An example of such an app is freedom app but as for me i want to have a list of sites to be blocked.